# Timer Stopping on Async Button Click

Tags: c#

the issue is simple my timer stops when I send a click and do something async, I don't want it to stop

The interface is pretty simple, I have 2 buttons for reading a .txt file from start to end. When button 1 pressed it needs to read using normal sync mode, this will pause the timer until it finishes, but when button 2 is pressed I excpect my timer to continue ticking and doing the reading async but when button2 is pressed it stops ticking as same in button 1 (Sync method)

Here is my code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = " ";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\alexd\Desktop\lorem.txt");
        var txt =  sr.ReadToEnd();
        textBox1.Text = txt;
    }

    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = " ";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\alexd\Desktop\lorem.txt");
        var txt = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        textBox1.Text = txt;

    }
}
```

Comment: Which line does the timer stop on?  Its possible `textBox1.Text = txt;` will freeze the UI.

Comment: It suppused to stop on button1 since its the same thread but when button2 pressed it is supposed the timer to continue while reading file

Comment: Well that's my logic

Comment: Which line in button2_click is it stopping on? Use your debugger. I bet it's on `textBox1.Text = txt;`. If txt is large, it will freeze your UI and the timer.

Comment: How big is "lorem.txt" ?

Comment: I'm not able to see exactly where exactly is stopping

Comment: It's 2.43mb .txt file, I made those lines like that so it would be more visible the difference between sync and async

Comment: I suspect it's stalling while it populates a text box with 2.43MB of text.

Comment: comment out `textBox1.Text = txt;` and I bet your timer keeps running.

Comment: Correct, it keeps running

Comment: Do you think trying with JSON file will be better?
The thing is I want to show the difference between async and sync with this example, which I thought it was easy

Comment: Actually your example proves async/await is working when you comment out that line. Simply because the timer does not stop.

Comment: You could instead of setting `textBox1.Text = txt;` just set it first to "Starting" before the async call and then to "Finished" after the async call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the file is not freezing the UI. The problem is populating a control with a huge string will freeze the UI (and your timer) as proven by commenting out:

```
textBox1.Text = txt;
```

If you want to show large amounts of text in your form, use a [RichTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) instead of regular Textbox.